# Problems launching tomcat/JBoss from IntelliJ

Tags: tomcat, jboss, intellij-idea, webserver

I have Intellij IDEA 9.0.4 set up to start a tomcat webserver and deploy my project on to it.  This has been working fine for some time but recently it has been failing silently.  When I tell it to run, it compiles things as required, tells me compilation is successful and stops there.  There are no error or warnings printed anywhere or in dialogs, but it does not start tomcat or even switch to the run tab.  The same thing happens when I try it in JBoss (which I have never tried before - I've just recently attempted setting this up for the first time).

I have tried manually launching tomcat from its startup.bat file and this seems to work fine.  I also tried downloading it again and that didn't help.  I'm using version 5.5.30.
I have not manually changed any relevant settings, but I did suffer a couple of power cuts recently and the problems seem to have been occurring since then, although I can't be sure of that correlation.

Does anyone know of something I could try/a configuration or log file I could check to see why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some bug in IDEA itself, probably caused by broken or incorrect configuration. Most likely there is corresponding exception in [idea.log](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) file.

It may help if you move/delete IDEA directories mentioned at the link above to start with all the default settings, then make vanilla Tomcat installation and configure it in IDEA, then try to create a new project and run it under Tomcat.

Comment: I have tried removing both the 'config' and 'system' folders from my local user area and then re-importing my project from scratch, but the problem persists - no errors or anything but the web-app doesn't start.  Do you think I need a complete re-install of IntelliJ?

Comment: I've just tried a complete re-install of IntelliJ too and that doesn't seem to have helped either.  I'm not sure what to try next...

Comment: I have this working now - all my configurations seemed to persist despite removing so much stuff, but a new configuration on top of the new install seems to be deploying.